# How to loop through a dynamically generated table row and fetch the values in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

i will appreciate your guidance on this please. 
I have an HTML form with about 4 fields whose values are posted to a tr row
of a table, rows been generated dynamically with jquery. At the click
of submit button after entering the values in the fields, the values are sent to my database table.The issue here is that in my php code, I can't seems to
be able to loop through the table to fetch these values. My code is as
shown below:

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" role="form"  class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" id="name">
  </div>
  <div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age[]" id="age"  />
  </div>
  <div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sex[]" id="sex"  />
  </div>
   <div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="scores[]" id="scores" />
   </div>
   <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="add_records[]"
id="add_records">ADD ROW</button>
   </div>
   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success name="submit_rec">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

THE PHP PART

```
<?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit_rec'])){
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'proj');

//processing the fied for name for instance
         if ($_POST['name']){
                $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name]);
                foreach ($name as $value) {
                echo $value; // does not echo any value, same with other fields!
        }
      }
    }
?>
```

AND THE JQUERY PART

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
        //script to add new table row
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var i=1;
    $("#add_records").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var age = $("#age").val();
        var sex = $("#sex").val();
        var scores= $("#scores").val();
        var delRow ='<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger my_butn"
id="del_btn"> - </button>';

        $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+age+"</td><td>"+sex+"</td><td>"+scores+"</td><td>"+delRow+"</td></tr>");
       $("tr>td:last").addClass('delete').addClass('del');
        i++;
</script>
```

Comment: Check this line in php part                 $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name]);
, near name you are missing quotes

Comment: I am having a similar problem, did you ever find the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your php part with,

```
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_rec'])) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'proj');

    //processing the fied for name for instance
    if ($_POST['name']) {
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
        foreach ($name as $value) {
            echo $value; // does not echo any value, same with other fields!
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Give it a try, it will work.

Comment: thanks @rahul_m but that doesnt seems to be the issue. the missing quote is in my real code on my text editor.

Comment: whats there in $_POST['name']

Comment: Thanks. $_POST['name'] is the field where candidates name are entered on the form. If for instance 10 students details are entered, meaning 10 rows are dynamically generated, how do i loop through t he table and fetch each of my name row, same thing for sex, age and scores fields. I hope you get the idea?